# How to include helper functions in multiple classes

Tags: actionscript-3, function, interface, include, package

I have two major classes, including about 7 files each, each containing 2 to 10 functions.

However, I have a utils.as file, containing about 10 simple explicit functions, that I wish to include in both.

I want to return a code as clean as possible, but I'm not sure what would be the best practice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use public static functions? For example the utils:

```
package myPackage.utils
{
 public class StringUtil
 {
  public static function substitute (msg : String, ...rest) : String
  {
  // replace all of the parameters in the msg string
  for (var i:int = 0; i < rest.length; i++)
  {
   msg = msg.replace(new RegExp("\\{"+i+"\\}", "g"), rest[i]);
  }
  return msg;
 }
}
}
```

A class

```
package myPackage{ 
import myPackage.utils.StringUtils;
public class myClass{
 public function myClass () {

 // use your Util class 
 var t = StringUtil.substitute("test {0}", "first value");
  trace (t);// output test first value
 } 

}}
```

Comment: Is that good practice? I've heard anything static is a lot slower.

Comment: Hope you don't just believe anything you hear ... But you can also use your brain and ask yourself why would the static keyword even exist if it's considered bad practice? What would probably be bad practice is to have an Utils class without static methods.

Comment: The LOOKUP of static are slower (http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1690) In a real application I don't think you will notice this. If performance realy mathers, write your Util inline every time you need it, or use the [Inline] tag http://renaun.com/blog/2012/09/using-the-new-inline-metadata-in-asc2/